# Mapping multiple entities under a single field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Is there a way to have a single field in an entity tied to multiple different entities?

I have a "Task" entity which can be associated with either the Customer entity or Supplier entity (never both). Right now both fields are separate.

I need to use this in my TaskType form so that users can select which Customer/Supplier to associate the Task with, ideally under a single field as I plan on adding more entities that it can associate with.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="tasks")
 */
private $customer;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Supplier", inversedBy="tasks")
 */
private $supplier;

public function getCustomer(): ?Customer
{
    return $this->customer;
}
public function setCustomer(?Customer $customer): self
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    return $this;
}
public function getSupplier(): ?Supplier
...etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following :

Ideally, I guess you want to share informations between `Customer` and `Supplier`. So we could introduce a new parent class, `Person` for example (I don't know which kind of responsibility they have, so we'll take the most "generic" class name), and use [Doctrine inheritance mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *  "customer" = "Customer",
 *  "supplier" = "Supplier"
 * })
 */
abstract class Person
{
  //... Fields, traits, embeddables...

  /**
   * A common attribute between our child classes
   * protected to respect encapsulation
   * 
   * @ORM\Column(type="text")
   */
  protected $name;

  /**
   * Here we define the general link to a task. It will be inherited by child classes
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Task", mappedBy="assignedTo")
   */
  protected $tasks;

  // public getters/setters...
}
```

I think [Class table inheritance strategy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) would fit your needs here, as you would like to add more entities later. That way, we can respect the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and add more child classes later instead of modifying a logic in only one class.

Also, I made the `Person` class abstract since we usually want to deal with `Customer` or `Supplier` instances. But depending on what you need, maybe you can remove the `abstract` keyword. In that case, you will have to include `Person` inside the discriminator map.

Of course, now `Customer` and `Supplier` have both to extend `Person` :

```php
//...
class Customer extends Person
//...

//...
class Supplier extends Person
//...
```

> Don't forget to remove shared fields (like `id`, for instance) from the child classes, it will be now inherited from `Person`

So then, in a Task, you are able to define the `ManyToOne` relation to a `Person` :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person", inversedBy="tasks")
 */
private $assignedTo;
```

Finally, for your Task form, let's have a select list with the names of all the persons :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Person;
use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      // other task fields
      ->add('assignedTo', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Person::class,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
      ]);
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'data_class' => Task::class,
    ]);
  }
}
```

It will select all the persons, regardless of the type.
You can then extend it later with other child classes !
I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer; the only problem with this method is I won't be able to associate other entities which aren't 'shared' with Customer/Supplier; such as I want to be able to associate a Task with a 'Contact', 'Employee', 'Email', 'Ticket' ...etc. Unless I'm mistaken, the class table inheritance strategy wouldn't cut it, or would it?

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstood your question, but it seems to me that if you want to tie a single field to multiple entities, you have to define a base class first for these entities, since you can not link a field to multiple entities types but only one...class table is only to have joins between parent table and child tables, in you sql db :)